# Python how to detect a change in executed code

Tags: python, git, cron, package

I have a Python package with an entry point at `__main__`. I will be running a nightly Cron job, and I want the Cron job to execute the package if it detects a change in the execution of the package. I will be using git hashes to perform the comparison between files and commits.

However, if I commit a change that affects a function that is NOT used based on the current execution from the `__main__` entry point, then I don't want the package to execute that night. How can I get around this issue?

Comment: Are you thinking about static analysis of unreachable code with something like this https://codeql.github.com/docs/codeql-language-guides/analyzing-control-flow-in-python/ or is that overkill?

Comment: Likely overkill, but interesting resource.

Comment: Since Git just stores commits, Git won't help solve the problem by itself. You can't get the information you want just from a hash ID. Note that a full and complete solution is equivalent to solving the halting problem, so you'll almost certainly want to settle for something less thorough....